# Transform the following Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Transform the differential equation:

\begin{equation}
x^2\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} + y^2\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}=0 
\end{equation}

Taking as new variables $u=x$, $v=1/y-1/x$, $w=1/z-1/x$. Obtain a new differential equation in terms of $u$, $v$ and $w$.

This isn't an exercise from formal course of differential equations, this is an exercise to practice derivating in several variables, etc. I'm kind of confused in this one, as when I apply the Chain Rule I haven't been able to separate completely the terms involving $x$, $y$ and $z$ and the terms $u$, $v$,$w$.

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

## Hint

$$z=z(x,y)=z(u,v)=\frac 1{w+1/x}=\frac1{w+1/u} \\ 
x^2=u^2\ \ and \ \ \ y^2=\{\frac 1{{v+1/u}}\}^2\\
 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=-\left(\frac1{w+1/u}\right)^{-2}\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial u}-1/u^2\right)$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I had written down the definition of $v$ wrong, its actually: $v=1/y-1/x$

Comment: Why is it that the third line isn`t  $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
+ \ \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Comment: It is just a copy paste mistake

Comment: In that case, what would $\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}$ be? Because you can`t get z in terms of $v$ unless you let a $y$ in your equation, which you don´t want.